# Add color bar in SphericalPlot3d in version 8

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to add a color bar in my spherical plot. I have tried the `BarLegend` command in version 8 but it seems not working. Could anyone help me out a bit? I wrote the following command:

```
SphericalPlot3D[
 1/((Sin[θ]^4*Cos[ϕ]^4*0.049896792) + (2*(Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ])^2*(Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ])^2*(-0.01555592)) 
      + (2*(Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(-0.030833372)) 
      + (Sin[θ]^4*Sin[ϕ]^4*0.011343866) + (2*(Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.007005355)) 
      + (Cos[θ]^4*0.025839216) + ((Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.01848854)) 
      + ((Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.020627753)) 
      + ((Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ])^2*(Sin[θ]* Sin[ϕ])^2*(0.031580823))), 
 {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesStyle -> Thick, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]
]
```

which generates following plot:

[image]

I want to put a color bar just beside the picture according to its value similar like a `BarLegend` command in 2D plot.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are either using a desktop installation of Mathematica v. 8 as you mention in the title, or webMathematica, or Mathematica online, as your tags imply?

Comment: A brute-force workaround would be to construct your own: `Row@{Show[plot, ImageSize -> 300], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-100, 100}}]}`, where `plot = SphericalPlot3D[...]`. This is [the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n07uF.png).

Comment: Docs say `BarLegend` was added in v9.0. But there may be other solutions, e.g. you could always build your own: `Graphics[
 {ColorData["Rainbow"][#/10], Rectangle[{0, 0 + #}, {1, 1 + #}]} & /@ 
  Range[10]
 ]` you'd have to add proper rescaling and ticks etc... which could be used with MarcoB's suggestion.

Comment: In mathematica 8 you have to use the package ``<< PlotLegends` ``. Check [this link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html) for details.

Comment: @MarcoB:  I am using desktop installation of Mathematica 8. I just tried your script and unfortunately it does not work here. However, the plot you have shown in your code is the perfect one which I am looking for. What should I do? I am getting the following error while running your code: "Set::wrsym: Symbol Plot is Protected." and "Show::gtype: ColorbarPlot is not a type of graphics"

Comment: @Sumit: PlotLegends is not working here...

Comment: @N.J.Evans: Your code is working. But I am not getting how to add it in my 3D plot could you please explain a bit more? I am not really experienced in Mathematica.

Comment: Try: `leg=Graphics[ {ColorData["Rainbow"][#/10], Rectangle[{0, 0 + #}, {1, 1 + #}]} & /@ Range[10] ]` then use MarcoB's workaround, `Row@{Show[plot, ImageSize -> 300], leg}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround that is valid for version 8.  Before `PlotLegends` was introduced I would simply make a `DensityPlot` when I needed a color bar to use as a legend:

```
r[θ_, ϕ_] := 
  1/((Sin[θ]^4*
       Cos[ϕ]^4*0.049896792) + (2*(Sin[θ]*
          Cos[ϕ])^2*(Sin[θ]*
          Sin[ϕ])^2*(-0.01555592)) + (2*(Sin[θ]*
          Cos[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(-0.030833372)) + (Sin[\
θ]^4*
       Sin[ϕ]^4*0.011343866) + (2*(Sin[θ]*
          Sin[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.007005355)) + (Cos[\
θ]^4*0.025839216) + ((Sin[θ]*
          Sin[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.01848854)) + ((Sin[\
θ]*
          Cos[ϕ])^2*(Cos[θ])^2*(0.020627753)) + ((Sin[\
θ]*Cos[ϕ])^2*(Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ])^2*(0.031580823)));
{plot, points} = 
  Reap[SphericalPlot3D[
    r[θ, ϕ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesStyle -> Thick, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], ImageSize -> 400, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[r[θ, ϕ] Cos[θ]]]];
Row[{plot, 
  DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, Min@points, Max@points}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 15, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The key here is to grab the range of plotted values while you make the plot so that your color bar matches with your plot.  Since your original plot scales the color with the `z` coordinate, I use `r[θ, ϕ] Cos[θ]` in the call to `EvaluationMonitor`.  If you colored via any other coordinate, or `r`, then you need to change that part of the code.